# Interpolation from discrete time fourier transform in python

Tags: fft, python, dft

I have a function that I sample from over one period.
I want to use the Fourier Transform to learn the function and then predict unsampled values.
Please see the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sample from the function for one period
t = np.linspace(0,1, num=30) * 2*np.pi
samples = np.cos(t) + np.sin(2*t + 2*np.pi/3)
plt.scatter(t, samples)

# Fourier transform
dft_coef = np.fft.fft(samples)

# Predict outcome for arbitrary not observed angle t'
def predict(t_, dft_coef):
    # TODO
```

Here is the plot:

[image]

The goal is to write a function `predict` that will calculate arbitrary values of the function. Can someone help me go from this discrete case to continuous prediction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your signal is periodic you can simply interpolate by padding zeros in the frequency domain. This is equivalent to infinite circular `sinc()` interpolation and will in your case give "ideal" results.

In general the process is called "up sampling": the generic to do this is to insert zeros between the existing samples and than filter with a suitable low-pass or "interpolation" filter to remove the mirror images of the spectrum. Typically that's done using a polyphase FIR filter.

Comment: any code that I can use?

Answer (score 2):

I found this post from googling "`numpy fft interpolation`", and since the accepted answer does not do what the question asked I thought I would supply my solution for FFT interpolating arbitrary values:

```
def fft_interp(coeffs, x):
    # 1D FFT interpolate for arbitrary x
    # assume x is periodic on [0,1] interval
    size = len(coeffs)
    kn = np.fft.fftfreq(size)
    eikx = np.exp(2.j*np.pi*x*size*kn)
    return np.dot(coeffs, eikx) / size
```

and here is for an array of arbitrary values:

```
def fft_interp_vec(coeffs, xv):
    size = len(coeffs)
    kn = fft.fftfreq(size)
    eikx = np.exp( 2.j*np.pi*size*np.outer(xv, kn) )
    return np.einsum('ab,b->a', eikx, coeffs) / size
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just join the lines by linear interpolation, Or use preexisting libraries like scipy. The method you are looking for is [scipy.interpolate.interp2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html).

Comment: Linear interpolation  gives poor results for higher frequencies. If you want to use standard interpolation, a spline or Lagrange would work better.